# delete cookies using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I  am working on Asp.Net Mvc and am creating a cookie using  in one page.I want when a user moves to her page the cookie gets deleted.Further if the same page (in cookie was created) is refreshed the cookie should not be deleted.How can i achieve this.

Comment: You can delete a cookie just by setting its expiration date in the past.

Answer (score 1):

quirksmode.org has some pretty handy [functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script) for creating/reading/manipulating/deleting cookies.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating the cookie, set the expires like this:

```
document.cookie="cookie_name=cookie_value; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";
```